system fails to run script that otherwise works fine?
I have a golang API that needs to run 24/7 for a nginx proxy backstream.
I have the following script, /root/api.sh:
#!/usr/bin/bash
cd /root/api && go run .

That runs fine manually, but the service fails to start:
/etc/systemd/system/api.service
[Unit]
Description=A go-lang API for the www frontend

[Service]
Type = simple
ExecStart=/root/api.sh

systemctl status api.service reports:
× api.service - A go-lang API for the www frontend
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/api.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2024-11-21 18:55:03 UTC; 2min 17s ago
   Duration: 118ms
 Invocation: e6e602afee2b4bf6b2d623c15fcbb65e
    Process: 343565 ExecStart=/root/api.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 343565 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Mem peak: 2.8M
        CPU: 50ms

